# Scala's icons don't appear in IntelliJ Idea 12

Tags: scala, ubuntu, intellij-idea

I'm using Scala plugin in IntelliJ Idea 12. I wonder, why don't the scala icons appear, whereas java ones do? That's the same for the other projects I have.

Previously on Ubuntu 12 it was ok (now I'm using Ubuntu 13).

[image]

Here is an exception from **idea.log:**

2

```
013-09-24 12:20:32,818 [   4599]  ERROR - .components.ComponentStoreImpl - Conflicting component name 'SbtSettings': class org.jetbrains.sbt.settings.SbtApplicationSettings and class net.orfjackal.sbt.plugin.settings.SbtApplicationSettingsComponent 
java.lang.Throwable
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ComponentStoreImpl.a(ComponentStoreImpl.java:202)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ComponentStoreImpl.a(ComponentStoreImpl.java:269)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ComponentStoreImpl.access$000(ComponentStoreImpl.java:44)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ComponentStoreImpl$1.run(ComponentStoreImpl.java:84)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:929)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ComponentStoreImpl.initComponent(ComponentStoreImpl.java:81)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.initializeComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:208)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.b(ComponentManagerImpl.java:215)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.access$1300(ComponentManagerImpl.java:55)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:587)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:630)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:242)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:229)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:211)
    at org.picocontainer.alternatives.AbstractDelegatingMutablePicoContainer.getComponentInstance(AbstractDelegatingMutablePicoContainer.java:75)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:412)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.a(ComponentManagerImpl.java:108)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.initComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:346)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl.load(ApplicationStoreImpl.java:82)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:543)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:197)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$2.run(MainImpl.java:141)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.d(IdeEventQueue.java:700)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:525)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:348)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
2013-09-21 12:20:32,821 [   4602]  ERROR - .components.ComponentStoreImpl - IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.3  Build #IU-129.451 
2013-09-21 12:20:32,821 [   4602]  ERROR - .components.ComponentStoreImpl - JDK: 1.7.0_25 
2013-09-21 12:20:32,821 [   4602]  ERROR - .components.ComponentStoreImpl - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
2013-09-21 12:20:32,821 [   4602]  ERROR - .components.ComponentStoreImpl - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
2013-09-21 12:20:32,821 [   4602]  ERROR - .components.ComponentStoreImpl - OS: Linux
```

Comment: Do you have a Scala facet under Project Settings -> Modules -> (your module)?

Comment: @alexwriteshere, yes I do.

Comment: Please try `File` | `Invalidate Caches` | `Invalidate and Restart`. Check [idea.log](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23352446) for exceptions. Try a [new Scala plug-in](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/SCA/Scala+Plugin+Nightly+Builds+for+Leda) version.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, I did all of that, please take a look at the exception.

Comment: This error comes from the SBT plug-in. See if disabling it solves the problem.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, it doesn't.

Comment: Any other exceptions?

Comment: @CrazyCoder, no, only a few warnings and many info.

Comment: Try [IDEA 12.1.4](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html) or [12.1.5](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12.1+EAP).

Comment: @CrazyCoder, заработала, однако.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by IDEA 12.1.3 incompatibility with the Scala plug-in. IDEA 12.1.4 should fix it.